# Why are two separate Gmail accounts receiving the same messages and synchronizing changes

Tags: gmail

I don't know how it happens, but my two separate Gmail accounts are receiving the same emails.  Also, when I delete a message from one of the accounts, it is also deleted from the other account.

- I tried all the solutions I found on the internet but none of them worked.
- I confirmed that POP and IMAP access are disabled
- there are no accounts listed in "**Check email from other accounts**"

I don't know what else I can do.

I am not a native English speaker and apologize if anything is unclear.

Comment: Select a matching message in the two accounts.  Edit your question to include the headers from both emails.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.